# autoSizeColumn, width issue in POI 3.9 for large data

Tags: java, apache-poi

I'm generating excel sheet with large data using "`SXSSFWorkbook`" POI 3.9
and finally doing the autoSizeColumn for all the column. Below is the code snippet.

Here I'm using the

```
SXSSFSheet mySheet = (SXSSFSheet) workbook.createSheet("New");
mySheet.setRandomAccessWindowSize(1000);
```

> **Issue:**  If the row count is less than 1000, All the columns are
>   auto-sized and looks good. If the row count is greater than 1000 ,
>   columns are not auto-sized.

```
    for(int rc=0;rc<=rcdata.length;rc++){
    Row row= mySheet.createRow(rc);
    for(int hr=0;hr<data.length;hr++){
       Cell cell = row.createCell(hr);
       cell.setCellValue(list.get(he));
   }
}   

if(mySheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows()>0){
    for(int i = 0; i<mySheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();i++) {
        mySheet.autoSizeColumn(i);
    }       
}
```

Comment: Why have you chosen version 3.9?

Comment: Its an existing code in my production.

Comment: You need to upgrade, then turn on column size tracking

Answer (score 0):

You should call [`trackAllColumnsForAutoSizing`](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xssf/streaming/SXSSFSheet.html#trackAllColumnsForAutoSizing--) at the beginning to get this fixed, however this will have a performance impact.

You are using a `SXSSFSheet` with a `RandomAccessWindowSize` of `1000`. this is a RAM usage optimized implementation holding only the latest 1000 rows in memory, if you create more rows than this limit, the rows are temporally written to disk and the older rows can no longer be accessed. trying to get the rows value returns just `null` although there was a written to it. This is an optimization to reduce the required RAM as you no longer hold the complete workbook data in memory. However to autosize a column you need to access every row in it. So this method is simply not supported when using this kind of worksheet.